# Regex with awk to print capturing group

Tags: regex, awk

I am trying to extract two capturing groups using Awk and regular expression.

Input file contents:

```
 1. 2023-12-24T07:00:00 2152  4078  information.cp 253  TEST  Verifying certificate completed for 'C:\test file1.exe', SHA1: 'efdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754ee' lookup took: '57969' nanoseconds,
 2. Test123
 3. Upperpoint
 4. 2023-12-24T08:00:00 2152  4078  information.cp 253  TEST  Verifying certificate completed for 'C:\testfile2.exe', SHA1: 'ffdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754dd' lookup took: '57970' nanoseconds,
```

Trying to achieve: I only want to check if a line has this string `information.cp` then capture file path like `C:\test file1.exe` and SHA1: 'efdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754ee'

I wrote this Awk code to print first capture group (using lookaheads, non-capturing group and named capturing groups)

```
awk 'match($0, ".*?(?=information\.cp)\w+\.(?:\w+\s+)+'(?<path>[^']+)',\s+SHA1:\s'(?<Sha1>[^']+)'.*", m) {print m[1]}' logs
```

I am using macOS and getting error for regex. Looks like awk does not like the regex syntax

`Error: zsh: parse error near` )'`

Comment: awk uses [ERE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) regex which does not support lookaheads, named capture groups, etc. `(?:abc)` will attempt to match `?:abc` literally

Comment: Aside from that, you are attempting to nest single-quotes inside single-quotes, which is why zsh is complaining

Comment: Thanks. Regarding single quote, I tried escaping the single quotes inside the regex but still same. I think awk uses single-quote around match?

Comment: Read the zsh manual for how single-quotes work

Comment: if the line format is fixed, something this might work: `awk '/information\.cp/ && /TEST Verifying certificate completed/ && $(NF-5)=="SHA1:" { print substr($(NF-4),2,40) }' logs`

Comment: also, in POSIX awk, `match` does not have a third argument. perhaps you are using `gawk` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you're trying to do, using any awk:

```
$ awk -F\' '/information\.cp/{print $2, $4}' file
C:\test file1.exe efdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754ee
C:\testfile2.exe ffdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754dd
```

Any time you find yourself writing a lengthy regular expression keep in mind [this quote](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
> regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

Regarding your question and the comments below it:

1. `(?:abc)` is a PCRE construct while awk uses EREs. Any awk could do anything with that construct since the meaning of a rgegexp repetition metachar like `?` at the start of a regexp [sub]exression is undefined by POSIX. The most likely things any given awk might do are either treat it literally (which I think the current version of GNU awk does, idk about any others now or in the past/future) or ignore it.
2. You can't nest single quotes in any shell. To use it in a string you can write `"foo'bar"` or `'foo'\''bar'` but not any variation of `'foo\'bar'`. To use a single quote in an awk script that's delimited by single quotes, as they all should be when calling awk from shell, see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.
3. GNU awk (and a couple of others, but not the BSD awk that's the default on MacOS) supports capture groups in `gensub()` and `match()`, see the GNU awk man page for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Awk doesn't have the concept of capture groups, but you can do this in `sed`:

```
sed -E -n 's/.*information\.cp[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.([A-Za-z0-9_]+[[:space:]]+)+'\''([^'\'']+)'\'',[[:space:]]+SHA1:[[:space:]]'\''([^'\'']+)'\''.*/\2\t\3/p' logs
```

Notice also how the Perlisms `\s`, `\w`, `(?...)` etc are not generally available in Awk, `sed`, `grep`, or other traditional Unix tools.  The `-E` option is nonportable, but where available, selects the somewhat more modern ERE regex syntax than what traditional `sed` originally supported.

This uses single quotes around the `sed` script, but breaks out of them occasionally to expose a single unquoted but backslashed literal single quote. In other words, `'foo'\''bar'` encodes a quoted `foo`, an unquoted but escaped literal single quote, and `bar`; when the shell is done parsing this, the result is the string `foo'bar`. (As an alternative, you could use double quotes around the `sed` script, but then some characters would have to be backslashed. Probably spend some time studying the [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) – Zsh and all other Bourne-like shells basically have the same quoting mechanisms.)

The `\w+\.` immediately after `information\.cp` prevents this from matching your example; if you take out the corresponding `[A-Za-z0-9_]+\.` from my attempt and replace it with simply `.*`, you get a match. Demo: https://ideone.com/KweF6Z

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think BSD sed, the default on MacOS, even when called with `-E` supports `\s` or `\w`, that's just GNU sed AFAIK. They would both support `[[:alnum:]_]` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9_]` though.

Answer (score 1):

> using lookaheads

GNU `AWK` does not supported that.

> if a line has this string `information.cp` then capture file path like
> `C:\test file1.exe` and SHA1: 'efdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754ee'

This can be done using two separate regular expression, I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
 1. 2023-12-24T07:00:00 2152  4078  information.cp 253  TEST  Verifying certificate completed for 'C:\test file1.exe', SHA1: 'efdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754ee' lookup took: '57969' nanoseconds,
 2. Test123
 3. Upperpoint
 4. 2023-12-24T08:00:00 2152  4078  information.cp 253  TEST  Verifying certificate completed for 'C:\testfile2.exe', SHA1: 'ffdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754dd' lookup took: '57970' nanoseconds,
```

then

```
awk '/information[.]cp/{match($0,/\047C:[^\047]*\047/);path=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2);match($0,/SHA1: \047[^\047]*\047/);sha=substr($0,RSTART+7,RLENGTH-8);print "path",path,"sha",sha}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
path C:\test file1.exe sha efdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754ee
path C:\testfile2.exe sha ffdfe54bce9edc227bee03bc61cbfaa8b3c754dd
```

Explanation: I am using [String Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) `match` and `substr`. As using `'` would be seen as termination of code I use `\047` to denote that character. Only for lines containing information.cp (note I put . in bracket so it means literal dot, not any character) I am using match to detect position of `'C:` followed by anything but `'` zero-or-more time followed by `'` and get substring which result in removal of `'`, similarly I do for SHA1, but I remove 7 leading characters, which are `SHA1: '`, retrieved substrings are stored in variables path and sha respectively. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes path always starts with `C:` if this does not hold adjust it accordiingly.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*